# How to convert images to pdf using PHP?

Tags: php, pdf

Can anyone have an idea how to convert images to pdf using PHP?

Any response will be appreciated.

Thanks...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have ImageMagick installed and `exec` permissions,

```
exec("convert foo.jpeg foo.pdf");
```

Comment: @no: i hope it works.. i will try it then.. if it works or not... i will post the result.. :D thanks for the response..

Comment: @no: i tried it.. and it works like a charm.. thank you.. mhuaahugs...

Comment: I have a site that allows users to upload multiple files for multiple projects all at once.  I prefix the images w/ the project ID and then run this command using wildcards along w/ the prefix.  So it becomes: exec("convert $ID*.* $ID.pdf");  -- Works great!

Comment: How did you get the pdf file ready to download? once you've converted?

Comment: i have the same trouble? exec("convert compute/" . $_SESSION['MM_Username'] . "savedImage.jpg compute/" . $_SESSION['MM_Username'] . "savedImage.pdf"); it doesnt work.

Comment: @TundePizzle says "it doesnt work" but gives no further insight. This doesnt work for me either, it converts the image's text content to pdf pages, but it does not convert the image to an image within a pdf page as expected.

Comment: I works for me now
$delay = 4500;
$shellout = exec("C:\DEV\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltoimage --javascript-delay $delay $webpageURLWithChart $outputImageFileName");

Answer (score 1):

You may use, MPDF and Normal PHP upload function to convert image into pdf.
Just follow the below steps.
Create a form to upload the file field "jpgtoconvert"

```
<?php
   $mpdf = new mPDF();
   $file = $_FILES['jpgtoconvert']['tmp_name'];
   $size =  getimagesize ( $file );
   $width = $size[0];
   $height = $size[1];
   $mpdf->WriteHTML('');
   $mpdf->Image($file,60,50,$width,$height,'jpg','',true, true);
   $mpdf->Output($filename);
?>
```

This function should output the pdf on the browser.

Comment: https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf

Answer (score 0):

if you have Ghostscript and Imagemagick install on system than you can try this :

```
exec("convert -geometry 1600x1600 -density 200x200 -quality 100 $pdf_path $image_path");
```